# HTML CSS 100 percent height issue - a JQuery Mobile panel example

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, responsive-design, height

There are tons of posts on using the full height of a screen no matter the size via HTML/CSS.  Typically, though, they are cases where someone wants their entire webpage to layout with a header/footer and stretchable middle.  I thought it would be good to post a real world example I'm working with wherein a component (not the full page) needs this.

I thought I'd try to build a chat client into a JQuery Mobile panel.  So you hit a button, a nice looking panel pops out from the right into which you type a message, hit the send button, and close the panel.

Here's a JFiddle and the code is down below:

http://jsfiddle.net/7G8JK/9/

I'm new to JQuery Mobile so the styling of that panel leaves a lot to be desired.  But you get where I'm going with it.  The main hurdle at this point is that white area in the middle - the area meant to display chat messages - class "messagesdiv".  Would like it to stretch to fill all available height.  In essence I'd like not to hard code any sizes (currently that area is hard coded to 242x200 just to make it appear).  Is this possible?  If so, how?

HTML:

```
<!-- rightpanel3  -->
<div data-role="panel" id="rightpanel3" data-position="right" data-display="overlay" data-dismissible="true" data-theme="a">

    <div class="containerchat">
        <div class="headerchat">CHAT</div>
        <div class="bodychat">
            <div class="messagesdiv"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="footerchat" data-role="fieldcontain">                                
            <input type="text" id="text" name="name" value="" data-role="none">
            <input id="btnSendMsg" type="button" value="Send" data-corners="false" data-inline="true"/>
        </div>
    </div>

</div><!-- /rightpanel3 -->


<!--Rest of the page-->
<div data-role="header"></div>

<div data-role="content">
        <a href="#rightpanel3" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">Overlay</a>
</div>

<div data-role="footer"></div>
```

CSS:

```
    .headerchat { height: 30px; background: #0000FF; color: white }
    .bodychat { background: #333333; }
    .messagesdiv { width: 242px; height:200px; background: white }
    .footerchat { background: #999999; }
    #text {
        width: 100px;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning in your CSS (the ui-panel-inner sizes the jQM panel to the height of the page):

```
.ui-panel .ui-panel-inner, containerchat {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
}
.headerchat {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;left: 15px;right: 15px; height: 30px;
    background: #0000FF; color: white;
}
.bodychat {
    position: absolute;
    top: 46px; bottom: 61px; left: 15px; right: 15px;
    background: #333333;
}
.messagesdiv {
    width: 242px;
    height:100%;
    background: white
}
.footerchat {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;left: 15px;right: 15px; height: 60px;
    background: #999999;
}
#text {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Here is your jsFiddle updated with the above CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/7G8JK/13/

Comment: Boom.  Winner.  Thanks much.  Had me a bit vexed.  Now all I have to do is fix up my crappy styling :)  Just learning this jQuery Mobile so this should be fun.  Gonna pull this up on all browsers to see if all is good.  Back in a bit.  Will mark accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .css - works for me. Maybe you have to play around with some of your div heights to fit your site exactly.

You've forgotten some other elements to inherit the base height of your site

**CSS:**

```
.headerchat { height: 30px; background: #0000FF; color: white }
.bodychat { background: #333333; height:100%;}
.messagesdiv { width: 242px; height:100%; background: white }
.footerchat { background: #999999; }
#text { width: 100px;}
.containerchat, div[data-role="panel"], div[data-role="panel"] .ui-panel-inner {
   height:100%;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/7G8JK/12/